# Grub stuck on "Grub loading"

Tags: grub, multi-boot

So, on my laptop I have two OS'es. Debian Squeeze and Windows 7. My problem is that Grub doesn't load anything. It stops on the message " Grub Loading.". Now I am trying to solve that problem using Parted Magic distribution. I guess that the main cause which gave a rise to everything is the improper Windows shutdown. What I mean is that Windows seems to be hibernated. I must have closed my notebook's lid too fast and it could have caused problems. My question is: is there a way I can fix everything? Maybe there is a possibility to wake up Windows or close it properly using Windows CD or maybe there is a useful command in linux which could make my day.

Comment: if anyone encounters likewise problem, this was helpful for me, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix especially boot-repair tool